# Blood flow in a circular maze?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

How can I create an animation in flash as3 in which I can show a blood stream ppassing through a circular maze?
for example, here's a maze: http://lonestar.texas.net/~dianes/labyrinth/maze.jpg
I want to make blood flow through that maze like in veins... Or better that that if I could make a circular venular image and make blood flow through it in smooth motion.

I'm trying to make an analog clock, in which I want to keep this venular circle as the background. I don't have much knowledge in as3, but I'll try to understand if there's a code for this...

Also if it can also be possible to get the blood around the border of some text (logo)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to first learn animation in Flash - this can likely be done simply by using movie clips in Flash (with perhaps a little bit of scripting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Animation

The simplest way would be to do the animation, without any code, with Flash. I assume you have only one animation to do, the maze and/or logo won't change.

The idea is to use your maze as a mask and have the blood in a layer below. Then you may draw the flow of blood with the brush frame by frame quite roughly (it will be masked anyway).

### Code

Using some code will be more complex. The only advantage is that it's dyanmic and will adapt to any shape, I don't know if it is what you want.

1. I would first choose the first point, the origin of the blood stream and paint it red.
2. Then I would use a [convolution matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ConvolutionFilter.html) to do a dilation of this pixel.
3. Then I would remove the pixels that do not belong to the masking shape (the maze)
4. I would compare this image to the image given by the previous iteration, if it is not the same, I would loop to 2.